# Approaches to handle stuck std::thread and to restart new thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I am trying to optimize a  C++ multi threading problem in which i have created three threads from the main function using [std::thread](http://%3Chref%20http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/%3E)

I want to know is there any approach by which I can handle situation like if 
 one of the worker thread got stuck somewhere I want to know about it 
 programmatically not by running and restart the stuck thread.

Comment: You can't kill a thread using `std::thread`, which of course means you can't ***re***start it.

Comment: Find the problem why that thread is stuck and fix that in 1st place.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i know that btw thanks for the reply

Comment: user0042 yes that is the one option which i can do, i was asking about how to know thread health . if process is stuck because of some thread instead of killing process i thought of restarting thread .

Comment: @navy It's your only option to do that. Don't fix the symptoms of a problem but its origin.

Comment: Debug it. Run a debug build and when you suspect the thread isn't okay put a breakpoint at the beginning of the thread function, step through it and inspect what is going on...